# don't know why the program is crashing

Tags: c, crash

I have written a code to find nth ugly number(a number which has at least one prime factor grater than 5) where n is a given input. my program runs well if the user inputs something less than 240. But if input gets bigger than that, program crashes!. My question is if it is a time consuming problem then it should take time but why the program crashes? I have used double everywhere so it might not be the matter of variable capacity!!
my code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double primes[1000]={2,3,5};
int serial=3;
double next_prime()
{
    double f=primes[serial-1]+2;
    int count;
    for(count=1;primes[count]<=(sqrt(f)+1) && count<serial;count++){
        if(fmod(f,primes[count])==0){
            f+=2;
            count=1;
        }
    }
    return primes[serial++]=f;
}
int main()
{
    double ugly_serial=12,ugly_number=16,j;
    int c,count,loop,input;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    while(ugly_serial<input)
    {
        loop=0;
        for(c=3;primes[c-1]<=sqrt(ugly_number);c++){
            j=next_prime();
        }
        for(count=3;count<c;count++){
            if(fmod(ugly_number,primes[count])==0){
               loop=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(loop==0){ugly_serial++;}
        ugly_number++;
    }
    printf("%.0lf",ugly_number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gdb is your friend.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html

Comment: In the first inner `for` loop in `main`, are you sure `c` won't get over `1000`? Use a debugger to find out if it's there the crash is, and if so what the value of `c` is. Otherwise, well, still use a debugger! It should really be the first thing you do when you have a crash. It will help you locate the place of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you understand _why_ it crashed.

Comment: humans dont make the best debuggers, but im going to go on a hunch it has something to do with the `primes` array and all the `for` loops which are reading from it in a seemingly incomprehensible way

Comment: well.. i am a beginner and i may not know many things.. but i use codeblocks 10.05 and gdb debugger is supposed to be included with it! but it's giving me no error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have compiled and run your code. The program works fine with all the input I have tried, including 56565.

Are you sure you are running the most recently compiled version of your program?

Comment: i am using codeblocks 10.05. what are you using?